# How do I make BSD seq not output + and e when using large numbers?

Tags: osx, bsd, seq

Say I run `seq 4000000 4100000`, I want seq print the numbers, as quoted from the `man` page, "from first (default 1), to near last as possible". Just like the GNU seq does.

But the output of my command is

```
4e+06
4e+06
4e+06
4e+06
4e+06
4.00000e+06
4.00001e+06
```

I want it to be

```
4000000
4000001
4000002
```

etc.

```
4099999
4100000
```

I thought that maybe `-w` could fix it but I am not sure what input to give it, giving it no input makes the output the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to display the results without scientific notation? Try this:

```
seq -f "%.0f" 4000000 4100000
```

So I'm actually changing the format (using `-f`) into a floating-point format with 0 decimal places (`%.0f`)

On my Mac this results in:

```
4000000
4000001
4000002
4000003
```

etc.

```
4099997
4099998
4099999
4100000
```